# How to transform all the dates in columns into a row series without disturbing the row below that

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, data-analysis

[image]

the data frame currently looks like this. How can the dates that are present in the columns transformed into a series with Column name Date with out changing the next row orientation.
Desired Result:
[image]

dates are discrete and continuous.

Any and All help is appreciated.
ps thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `melt` function in the following way:

```
pd.melt(df, id_vars=['State','District'], value_vars=['date','columns'])
```

Comment: It gives an error. "The following 'value_vars' are not present in the DataFrame: ['columns', 'date']", Also the 2nd image is the desired result in which all dates from 1st images should pe present as a df Series

Comment: You should replace the ['columns', 'date'] with the your actual columns date like this ['16/01/2021','16/01/2021.1',...]